# Angular / Typescript destroy new lib instance

Tags: angular, typescript

I am loading an instance of a library into a component like this:

```
createOne('targetelementid') {
    this.one = new mylib(targetElement);
}
```

I'm loading it in

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.createOne .... 
}
```

This is not a problem.

My issue is...how do I destroy the instance?

Comment: Why do you think you need to take care of that? Your instance is stored in a variable of the component instance, so it should get destroyed (it goes to garbage collection) once Angular destroys the component instance.

Comment: So it there a way to destroy it by code?

Comment: You can't destroy an instance, Javascript does that for you if there is no reference to that instance. So you could do something like this in your component: `onDestroy() {this.one = null;}`. But again, it's quite useless.